# How to add a base url for all NextJS routes?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a NextJS app, made with the new app router.

The structure is simple:

```js
- src
  - app
     - pages
       - home
         - page.tsx
       - dashboard
         - page
           - page.tsx
         - editor
           - page.tsx
```

So the 3 routes are:

- `/` (`pages/home/page.tsx`)
- `/dashboard/page` (`pages/dashboard/pages/page.tsx`)
- `/dashboard/editor` (`pages/dashboard/editor/page.tsx`)

I need to replace `pages` by `m/superapp` in my url. The routes should thus be:

- `/m/superapp` (`pages/home/page.tsx`)
- `/m/superapp/dashboard/page` (`pages/dashboard/pages/page.tsx`)
- `/m/superapp/dashboard/editor` (`pages/dashboard/editor/page.tsx`)

I tried to add a `middleware.ts` file in `src`, but it is never triggered:

```js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  return NextResponse.redirect(
    new URL("/m/superapp", request.url)
  );
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/dashboard/:path*", "/home"],
};
```

I also tried to add `basePath: '/m/superapp'` in `next.config.js`, without any success. The home page is never found and the url is never updated.

How to obtain the desired result?